# Google Maps Time Zone API get local time in UTC

Tags: javascript, google-maps, date, time, timezone

## Google Docs says:

> The local time of a given location is the sum of the timestamp parameter, and the dstOffset and rawOffset fields from the result.

timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset = local time in seconds in UTC

## Problem

I am trying to get the local time in the correct time zone.
I thought that new Date(timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset *1000) would return the local time in UTC, but instead I find that the actual numerical values are indeed in local time, in the wrong time zone (UTC).

## Example:

**timestamp:** 1456349190

**readable timestamp:** `new Date(1456349190*1000).toGMTString()` (Wed, 24 Feb 2016 21:26:30 GMT)

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.2079206,-84.5274616&timestamp=1456349190&key=${googleApiKey}`

*Returns:*

- **dstOffset**:  0
- **rawOffset**:  -18000
- **timeZoneId**: America/New_York

*Data:*

**Sum in seconds** = 1456349190 + 0 + (-18000) = 1456331190

**Sum in milliseconds** = 1456331190*1000 = 1456331190000

**Supposed Local Date** = `new Date(1456331190000).toGMTString()` (Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:26:30 GMT)

## Question

Shouldn't **readable timestamp** and **Supposed Local Date** be the same since both are in UTC?
Seems like **Supposed Local Date** should really be Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:26:30 **EST**

Is this correct?

If so it seems like I just need to extract the values I need (local hour) from **Supposed Local Date** and apply the correct time zone returned from google api **timeZoneId** (America/New_York) because 16:26:30 is the correct local time I need.

## Helpful Tips

These are some guidelines that helped me understand timestamp better:

"[The unix timestamp isn't affected by a timezone setting. Setting the timezone only affects the interpretation of the timestamp value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668144/3483001)"

Comment: "local time in UTC" is nonsensical.  A time is either local, or it is in UTC.  It can't be both.  If you live somewhere like Iceland, then your local time happens to be *aligned* to UTC year-round, but conceptually that is still **local** time.  If you live in the UK then your local time is aligned to UTC in the winter and one hour offset from UTC in the summer, and that is also your **local time**.  UTC has the same value for everyone on the planet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamp value indicates the seconds since 1/1/1970 **UTC**. Not local timestamp.
[image]

The Google API tells you the rawOffset of location is "-18000"
[image]

When you calculate the date with timestamp, you should align the unit in UTC.
**Because Date class treats the timestamp as UTC.**

In your explanation, **the value 1456331190000 is a local timestamp**, but the **Date class treats the value as UTC.**

This is your mistake point.

[image]

---

Here is the code (in Node.js)

[image]

Comment: This only works if process.env.TZ is changed to desired time zone (currently set to UTC). Is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: process.env.TZ is for the changing local time zone (because I'm not in NY). You don't need it.

Comment: my process.env.TZ has to remain UTC. I'm querying for different locations so I'm expecting to get different timezones. How can I get the local timestamp without depending on process.env.TZ. Something along the lines new Date(timestamp, timezone)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I just solve my problem adding this line:       `document.getElementById("utc_offset").value = place.utc_offset;`

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'

};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
//Get the UTC here and complete the form
  document.getElementById("utc_offset").value = place.utc_offset;
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform