# Yii2 set timezone before saving records

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Am saving time in integer format in mysql but its saved on a different timezone

This is the code that a using

```
$model->created_at = time();
```

This sets time in integer format eg :`1483881886`

The problem is that when i reconvert this time to hrs minutes and sec it points into a different timezone

I have also tried

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
then 
$model->created_at = time();  //the timezone is not set
```

How do i configure timezone in the unix time() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

time() return always unix timestamp referred to GMT `http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php`

But, after got $time in unix timestamp GMT, you can set timezone you want.

```
<?php
// If in php.ini default timezone is not set
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');

// Time in Unix timestamp GMT
$t = time();

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $t);

// From Unix time GMT to Africa/Nairobi
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Nairobi'));
echo 'Time GMT to Africa/Nairobi: '.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// From Unix time GMT to Europe/Rome
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo 'Time GMT to Europe/Rome: '.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

Comment: How do i format in unix time instead of y m d from this:  {$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');}}  that is to get integers

Comment: Unix timestamp is by definition referred to GMT. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668108/how-to-get-unix-timestamp-in-php-based-on-timezone

Comment: so in other words it means that when saving unix timestamp(in integers ) its saved according to gmt but when outputting it its when you add the timezone to match the current time

Comment: Yes, but only when you format output date in format different from timestamp ( 'U' format in date_format )

Comment: Thanks saved alot of time, Ive also found out that my php.ini was set to Germany and by setting to Africa/Nairobi also solves this plus your solution also works