# default timezone in twig via Timber library

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

When I use the `date()` function in a Twig template, it returns universal time, as opposed to the date *filter* which returns the correct time with the proper timezone applied.

I am using

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

in my theme's `functions.php` file for some other non-related functionality, which does appear to directly screw with these dates (when the line of code is removed, the date seems to render correctly). I could use the `date_modify` filter, but I'm working with a date between now and the daylight savings time switchover, so it unnecessarily affects what I'm trying to accomplish here.

After reading [the Twig docs on the `date()` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/date.html), I thought the following in my `functions.php` file would work, but it doesn't appear to have any affect:

```php
function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    $twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::class)->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
    return $twig;
}
```

So what's the correct way to tell Timber/Twig the timezone to use?

Comment: What you mean by "it doesn't have any effect". How are you verifying this?

Comment: @DarkBee With or without the `$twig->getExtension` line, `{{ date('now') }}` outputs the same time.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668342/446594)

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you, but that's a PHP answer and I could essentially create and manipulate my date objects before the template, but I'm really looking to solve the Twig issue. I have opened an issue ticket on github: https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2104

Answer (score 0):

First is necessary to add the Extension:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig\Extension\CoreExtension );
```

After that, you are free to use the same code you tried, available in the twig documentation.

So, the best option for sure would be use the timezone configured in WordPress.

The full code is:

```
public function add_to_twig($twig)
{
    /*HERE YOUR OTHER STUFF*/

    //Add the CoreExtension
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig\Extension\CoreExtension );

    //Get the timezone from Wordpress and use the extension to set the timezone
    $timezone = get_option('timezone_string');
    $twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::class)->setTimezone($timezone);

    return $twig;
}
```